# Tail and search in txt file

Tags: python, txt, tail

I need to make a search on a txt file. Originally I've thought to open the file and search for the word I'm looking for on the last line

```
remote_file = sftp_client.open('file.txt')

try:
        lst = list(remote_file.readlines())
        lastlines=lst[len(lst) - 1]
        print(lastlines)
        if SEARCH_MASTER in lastlines:
            Master='Master_SX'
finally:
        remote_file.close()
        ssh.close()
```

This worked quite fine, but now I need to do something similar but on the last 5 lines of this file.
I've tried to use the tail() function, adding the line

```
tailed_remote_file=remote_file.tail(3)
```

but It gave me error

> AttributeError: 'SFTPFile' object has no attribute 'tail'

Comment: `remote_file.readlines()[-5:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `tail` function in the python standard library. What I would suggest is a list slicing approach:

```
n = 5
lastlines = lst[-n:]
for line in lastlines:
    if SEARCH_MASTER in line:
        Master='Master_SX'
```

Further reading can be done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)

Comment: I think it is better to use `join` instead of `for` loop...

Comment: ok this works fine!thanks. I still have a question how can I start the reading from the last line? in my case can happen that the "SEARCH_MASTER" can be find in multiple lines while I'm interested in the last one only. Thanks again

Comment: just loop over `lastlines.reverse()` or via slicing again `lastlines[::-1]`

Answer (score 2):

some points to make your code better:

1. `lst[len(lst) - 1]`:
   if you want to obtain last element of a list, just use `-1`, `lst[-1]`, for second element from last: `lst[-2]` and so on
2. if you want 5 first elements, you can use `slice`s: `lst[:5]` and for 5 last elements: `lst[-5:]`
3. `readlines()` return `list` and don't need to convert it to `list`
4. instead of use `remote_file.close()` in `finally`, it is better to code like:

```
 with sftp_client.open('file.txt') as remote_file:
```

it closes the file automatically at the end

join:

```
if SEARCH_MASTER in " ".join(lst[-5:]):
    Master='Master_SX'
```